# AngularJS: How to manage and keep constants in a separate file

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem where I want to keep all constant strings, integers etc in a separate javascript file..The number of such constants is around 50.

The solutions I came across is using `angular.value` and `angular.constant`. Since using a specific constant in a controller/service will require explicit injection of that constant, therefore this is leading to lots of variables to be injected at the same time.

To avoid this I can group these values in an hash.

But is there any alternate way to handle constants across services and controllers?

Answer (score 3):

Can you group the individual constants as properties into one object ?

```
.constant('AllMyConstants', 
 {
    STATUS_BLAH        :     1,
    STATUS_MESSAGE1: 'blah blah'
 })
```

then else where you could inject as such

```
.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', 'AllMyConstants', function($scope,AllMyConstants) {
     if ($scope.status === AllMyConstants.STATUS_BAH) {
        //do something
     }
});
```

});

Comment: I think this is what OP mean `To avoid this I can group these values in an hash.`.

Comment: Ok I see. I don't see any alternate elegant way. @red-devil can you provide why you are seeking any alternate ways than "hash" ?

Comment: @bhantol I was seeking this as a curiosity, and was expecting alternate better ways to solve the problem. As this seemed little unorganised. Though it's fine, will go this way. Thanks. :)

Comment: Also is there a way to use these constants inside the html?

Comment: I came across this http://www.kidsil.net/2013/07/adding-config-to-your-angularjs-app/. Which looks elegant. Is using modules separately for each task is a good practice and how?

Comment: I don't see any way to utilize the constants unless we populate scope with it but it would seem like polluting the scope.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You have to use what the language provides you. In this case "hash" == Object. There really isn't anything else. Just go with it.